# nextflow regex on path

Tags: groovy, nextflow

The following works with strings:

```
Channel
.of('test1.fastq', 'test2.fastq', 'test1.bam', 'test2.bam')
.filter( ~/.*bam|.*1.fastq/ )
.view()
```

BUT not with paths. Is there a way to make this work with `path`?
E.g.

```
Channel
.fromPath( params.inputs )
.filter( ~/.*bam|.*1.fastq/ )
.view()
```

Thankn you!

Comment: what do you have in `params.inputs`? what do you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`filter`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#filter) operator also lets you specify a closure, which would let you use Groovy's *find* operator, for example:

```
params.inputs = '*.{bam,fastq}'


workflow {

    Channel
        .fromPath( params.inputs )
        .filter { it.name =~ /(\.bam|1\.fastq)$/ }
        .view()
}
```

Another way to do what you want, I think, would be to use the [find()](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#find(groovy.lang.Closure)) method, which returns the first value in a list or null if no such element exists. Note that, according to [the Groovy Truth](https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#the-groovy-truth), non-empty strings are coerced to true:

```
params.inputs = '*.{bam,fastq}'


workflow {

    Channel
        .fromPath( params.inputs )
        .filter { file ->
            ['.bam', '1.fastq'].find { file.name.endsWith(it) }
        }
        .view()
}
```